# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or The server response was: #5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first'

Tags: c#, outlook, smtp

What could be the solution for this error.

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or  The server response was: #5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first'`

using `(var smtpclient = new CvxSmtpClient("username", "password", 587))`

```
                        message.Body = email.message;
                        smtpclient.EnableSsl = false;
                        smtpclient.Send(message);                           
                        var param = new SqlParameter();
                        param.ParameterName = "@id";
                        param.Value = email.id;
                        db.ExecuteSql(queryUpdateEmailsToSend, param);
```

Comment: Please update the code provided sample since it's syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicatte(s): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869628/error-in-sending-mail-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP server refuses insecure connections.

You set `smtpclient.EnableSsl = false`, so the `SmtpClient` doesn't use SSL. Try setting it to `true`.

For more details have a look at the docs: [`SmtpClient.EnableSsl` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Even after setting smtpclient.EnableSsl = true. I'm getting this error "system" at system.net.mail.mailcommand.checkResponse(SmtpStatusCode StatusCode, String response)\r\n at system.net.mail.mailcommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn,

Comment: @ReshimmaPasupathi add the new error to your question since it doesn't seem to fit a comment and fix the issues with your initial question while you're on it.
Also, please format your content properly. Read [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).